# How to convert NULL to 0 in LEFT OUTER JOIN SQL Select statement

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that implements a LEFT OUTER JOIN to compile different tables in a single one. I want to be able to join results in a same table, but according to different parameters (where clause).

So, this is the structure of the tables I'm joining:

### dbo.Medios_Pauta

ID (PK - int)

Nombre (varchar)

UsrCr (varchar)

FechaCr (datetime)

### dbo.N_Preinscripcion

ID (PK - int)

Periodo (varchar)

MedioId (int)

...Other ones...

### dbo.N_Insc_Preg_Control

ID (PK - int)

IdPre (int - foreing key to dbo.N_Preinscripcion.ID)

### dbo.N_Insc_Posg_Control

ID (PK - int)

IdPre (int - foreing key to dbo.N_Preinscripcion.ID)

Ok, so the query I've built is working fine, but whenever there's a NULL value it will bring "NULL" in the table. I want to transform that NULL to zero (0).

I've tried using ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AND COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) but it still giving a NULL.

Here's the code of the query with ISNULL:

```
SELECT
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2],
    SUM([Inscritos_Preg].[regs1] + [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2])  AS [Inscritos]  
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs1]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Preg]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs2]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Posg]
        ON [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId] = [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId]   
GROUP BY 
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],  
    [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2]
```

And this is this query's result:

```
MedioId   regs1    regs2    Inscritos
1         8        9        17
4         75       16       91
23        16       NULL     NULL
24        2        NULL     NULL
25        164      127      291
28        8        NULL     NULL
29        3        1        4
30        1        2        3
```

Now, when I use COALESCE I'm getting the exact same result, with NULL. Here's the code:

```
SELECT
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2],
    SUM([Inscritos_Preg].[regs1] + [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2])  AS [Inscritos]  
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs1]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Preg]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs2]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Posg]
        ON [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId] = [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId]   
GROUP BY 
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],  
    [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2]
```

And the result:

```
MedioId   regs1    regs2    Inscritos
1         8        9        17
4         75       16       91
23        16       NULL     NULL
24        2        NULL     NULL
25        164      127      291
28        8        NULL     NULL
29        3        1        4
30        1        2        3
```

How can I replace those NULL with a zero (0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `COALESCE()` function which  returns the 1st non null value so if your column value is null then it will return 0

```
SELECT
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],
   COALESCE ( [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2],0) as regs2,
    SUM(COALESCE ([Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],0) +
    COALESCE ([Inscritos_Posg].[regs2],0)  AS [Inscritos]  
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs1]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Preg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Preg]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS [regs2]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 

            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control] 
                ON [dbo].[N_Insc_Posg_Control].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]

            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Inscritos_Posg]
        ON [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId] = [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId]   
GROUP BY 
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],  
    [Inscritos_Posg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2]
```

Comment: Using `COALESCE (SUM([Inscritos_Preg].[regs1] + [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2]),0)  AS [Inscritos]` here may have some unintended results. If `[Inscritos_Preg].[regs1]` is a non-null value, and `[Inscritos_Posg].[regs2]` is NULL, then the expression would evaluate to 0 since the `SUM()` would return a NULL. I think the OP would want the NULLs to be treated as 0s inside of the `SUM()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need `COALESCE()` in the outer query:

```
SELECT
    [Inscritos_Preg].[MedioId],
    [Inscritos_Preg].[regs1],
    [Inscritos_Posg].[regs2],
    SUM(COALESCE([Inscritos_Preg].[regs1], 0) + COALESCE([Inscritos_Posg].[regs2], 0))  AS [Inscritos]
```

Note that `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` would never be needed for `COUNT()`.

Comment: Just to expand a little, the reason the `NULL`s are showing up is because there is no value in the `LEFT` table to join to. Which is why you need the `COALESCE()` in the outer query.